# Ninja Forms - Stripe - No Such Plan

Tags: stripe-payments, ninja-forms

I'm using **Ninja Forms** with the plug-in **Stripe** to create a form for a client.

But when all the condition is ok, and i try a payement with my credit card.

I got this error when i click to submit :

> "No Such Plan - "Reference_of_my_NinjaForms_calcul"

I'm in "`test mode`" on the stripe config plug-in.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem [here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: btw, i need to be able to pay withtout plan.

Comment: Edit the question and add your comment _btw, i need to be able to pay withtout plan_ and add some examples of your code, read the help in my first comment